# Ms Project 2007 Adding Custom Field Gantt (doesn't appear)

Tags: vba, ms-project

With this code:

```
Sub CreateNewField()

Dim x As TableField
Dim Field As String

Field = "TestCustomField"

'Check if the Custom Field is already created
If (CustomFieldExists(Field) = True) Then
    MsgBox ("The Field Exists")
'If the Custom field doesn't exists
Else
    MsgBox ("Doesn't exist")
    CustomFieldRename FieldID:=pjTaskNumber1, NewName:=Field
    'Adding to the table
    Set x = ActiveProject.TaskTables(Application.ActiveProject.CurrentTable).TableFields.Add(pjTaskNumber1)

End If
'Calculate and adding graphical indicator to the Custom Field
CalculateCustomField (Field)
AddGraphicIndicator (Field)
End Sub
```

The code correctly modifies the custom field "Number 1" and adds it to the table, but it doesn't appear like a Column in the Gantt chart until I close Project and reopen it again. 
Is there another way to show the custom field in the Gantt chart without closing and reopening Project 2007 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely an old post now, but it still might be useful to have an answer.

I had kind of the same issue, I wanted to add  the existing field "Work" to the "Entry" Table. I managed to add it, but it was not showing in the table.

Now, to apply the changes, I simply open the table again by calling the TableApply method:

> appProj.TableEditEx "Entry", True, , , , , "Work"
>      appProj.TableApply "Entry"

It works fine for me.

Comment: Hello Aurélien,

Yes, this is very old, but I appreciate someone answering this doubt. It could be useful to other users!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old, so maybe you have moved on, but have you calculated the project and made sure that Application.ScreenUpdating = True?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im not using VBA anymore, and unfortunately i can't access to the file to check your answer, but i hope this could help anyone in the future who have the same problem. Thanks again! :)